# Angular2: How to know number of iterators on *ngFor

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I wanted to know the number of iterators on the ngFor so that based on that i can show or hide, the element, for example i want to do this that if number of iterator reaches it should stop iterating.
The whole template so far is that:

```
<p *ngIf = "heros2.length > 3"> 
    there are two many users
    </p>
    <div *ngIf = "heros2.length == 3">
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor = 'let hero1 of heros2'>
    there are many users
    {{hero1.name}}
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did this but its not allowed im getting parsing errors

Answer (score 9):

This is the syntax:

`*ngFor="let hero1 of heroes2; let i=index"`

Take a look at [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor)

Answer (score 4):

To get the index of an ngFor you need to use `*ngFor="let element of elements; let i=index"`, where "i" is the current index.
One method to stop the ngFor could be using a python strategy creating an array with the exactly number of the elements to iterate over:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of range(6); let i=index">
    {{ elements[i].name }}
</div>
```

Where the range function returns an array with 6 positions. At this way you could iterate over the elements in a defined count.